# Why is my Jenkins failing for the first build and then succeeds from the next build onwards even though there is no change?

Tags: jenkins, tortoisesvn

So, I come in the morning and give a Jenkins build which is from an svn repository it fails. But the next build succeeds without any changes. The error I am getting is below.

> [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // node
>   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   hudson.scm.SVNRevisionState cannot be cast to
>   hudson.scm.SVNRevisionState   at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:756)    at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:897)     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Finished: FAILURE

Below is how my stage for checkout looks like :

```
stage('Clone repository') 
        bat 'cd "C:/Microservices"'
        bat 'svn upgrade'
        bat 'svn update'
        checkout scm
    }
```

I am clueless on what is happening. My TortiseSVN version is 1.13.1 and my Jenkins version is 2.190. If someone can help me on this I'd be really thankful.

[image: Stage view]

Comment: Do you use the automatic checkout or do you checkout your project manually? Can you add the stage where you execute the checkout, please?

Comment: stage('Clone repository') {
        bat 'cd "C:/Microservices"'
        bat 'svn upgrade'
        bat 'svn update'
        checkout scm
The above code is my stage which does scm checkout

Comment: Thanks for the addition but it would be great if you could add it to your question. Otherwise people will miss it.

Comment: Sure, I will add it. Thank you.

Comment: @mkemmerz do you have any idea on the above problem I posted?

Comment: unfortunately I do not, sorry

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-27079). According to some comments on the issue, it could be due to a bug in the Subversion plugin or the Multiple SCMs plugin. I would try to upgrade one or both plugins.

Comment: I have upgraded both and still facing the same issue. Any other workaround for this ?